# There is a problem on my website checkout page M2

Tags: magento2

**zip code Field**

> not show in check out page, Anyone knows what the problem is this,

[image]

**Thanks in advance:**

Comment: pls provide information in detail

Comment: @Ali Hussain i don't know how it happened  can you pls help me

Comment: try disabling your custom modules. disable all of them. run compile, clean cache and then check

Comment: @AliHussain My partner changed here public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.php

Comment: for show custom field

Comment: we never change in core files,, that's how magento recommends. can you try reverting it and check again. then create custom module and over ride and work on that one perhaps?

Comment: Yes i know,  i did reverting but nothing happened,

Comment: that's very sad, try replacing vendor from original zip?

Comment: any setting on admin dashboard zip code hide show

Comment: no you need to download fresh instance if you don't have one. then only replace your vendor with working directory

Comment: @AliHussain I am working on live site, if i download fresh instance any problem create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101545/discussion-between-ranjeet-gautam-and-ali-hussain).